# load more button in reactjs by using functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following ReactJS code:

```
     function SolutionsSection({solutions}) {
         const mainSolutions = solutions.slice(0, 4);
         const restSolutions = solutions.slice(4);
         const [isShown, setShow] = useState(false);
          return (
           <div>
             <SolutionSectionBox
               isShown={isShown}
               mainSolutions={mainSolutions}
               restSolutions={restSolutions}
             />
              {/*below is my button component*/}
             <SolutionsSectionAllServices
               setShow={setShow}
               isShown={isShown}
             />
         </div>
        );
       }
```

I have 28 "solution" information in backend. I can successfully fetch that informations and pass to my "SolutionsSection" component.

"mainSolutions" show first 4 solutions, "restSolutions" show rest 24 solutions when "load more" button was clicked. With useState I deciding show or hide my restSolutions.

Now my question is, how can I load my solutions information data by chunks, I mean in begining we should see first 4 solutions, then by clicking "load more" button show 8 solutions information, then again by clicking on button show next 12... .
I need something like this: [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-load-more-array-slice-forked-k2kkx)

Please help me to resolve that problem I am new in react.

Comment: What you could do is have a state properties  as `counter` and `nextSolutions`. As soon as user hits load more increment that `counter` and also update `nextSolutions` by pushing 4 rows every time when counter is increased.

Comment: @MeetZaveri please if you can show me in code, thanks

Comment: Sure! I will show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most naive approach.

Here are the properties and the action handler

```
const solutionsArr = solutions;
const [nextSolutions, setNextSolutions] = useState([solutions.slice(0, 4)]);

const onLoadMore = () => {
  let base = nextSolutions.length;
  let newResultArr = solutionsArr(base, base + 3);

  // appending new result to arr
  setNextSolutions([...nextSolutions, ...newResultArr]);
};
```

So for first load more,

`base -> 4 (length) as starting index and 7 as ending index (4,7)`

`2nd (8,11)`

`3rd (12,15)`

And so on ...

Comment: I tried as you said, my code is now working.I took your code as example and change mine